# How to run multiple hazelcast cluster in one deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hazelcast

I'm deploying hazelcast on k8s using the [helmchart](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast) on github currently on revision `5.3.2`.

How would one go about running two clusters, say *dev_cache* and *qa_cache* in one helm deployment each with different members? Is that possible?

I see the fields

```
hazelcast:
   javaOptions:
     existingConfigMap: xxx
```

and

```
configurationFiles: #any additional Hazelcast configuration files
```

in the `values.yaml` but am unable to find any documentation on how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one Helm deployment, you always run one Hazelcast cluster. You need to run Helm command twice to create 2 separate Hazelcast clusters.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know. It felt like it might be possible to add multiple hazelcast.xml configurations to create cluster groups inside the same deployment.